# Hadamard product for vector list in r

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to do Hadamard product (in R) for column vector whose element is a row vector. To be more precise, let `X=list(R1,R2)`, with `R1` and `R2` are two row-vectors of the same length. I wanted to create a matrix (which is obviously a list) `A=[A11, A12; A21, A22]` with `A11=R1oR1`, `A12=R1oR2`, `A21=R2oR1`, `A22=R2oR2`, where o denotes the hadamard product. Any suggestions on how to perform this product without using for looping in R, more like in the matrix form style? Thanks a lot.

Comment: BudhiSurya; please consider marking the answer below with the tick mark; some info https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Hadamard product is just entrywise multiplication which is `*` in R but to get the 2x2 matrix/list from the list `X` shown below we can try any of the following.

**1)** Using base R we have the following one-liner:

```
X <- list(R1 = 1:3, R2 = 4:6) # test data

m <- matrix(sapply(X, function(x) lapply(X, `*`, x)), 2)
```

giving this 2x2 matrix where we can use `m[[i, j]]` to extract the i,jth element of `m`.

```
m
##      [,1]      [,2]     
## [1,] Integer,3 Integer,3
## [2,] Integer,3 Integer,3

str(m)
## List of 4
##  $ : int [1:3] 1 4 9
##  $ : int [1:3] 4 10 18
##  $ : int [1:3] 4 10 18
##  $ : int [1:3] 16 25 36
##  - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2

m[[1,2]]
## [1]  4 10 18
```

**2)** or even simpler but more tedious:

```
with(X, matrix(list(R1 * R1, R1 * R2, R2 * R1, R2 * R2), 2))
```

**3)** Another approach is to produce a matrix of character expressions, `m.ch`, using `outer` and then parse and evaluate it.

```
m.ch <- outer(names(X), names(X), paste, sep = "*")
array(lapply(parse(text = m.ch), eval, X), dim(m.ch))
```

### Matrix as output

Although the question explicitly states it wants a list as the answer if you were also interested in a matrix as output such that its blocks are the entries of `m` then we can use the following where the Matrix package is pre-installed with R so it does not have to be installed.

```
library(Matrix)

Xmat <- do.call("rbind", X)
matrix(t(KhatriRao(Xmat)), 2, byrow = TRUE)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
## [1,]    1    4    9    4   10   18
## [2,]    4   10   18   16   25   36
```

or to derive this matrix from `m` from (1) use:

```
matrix(unlist(m), 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, Grothendieck for your quick response, appreciate that. I like the first approach. My next question is how the derived block matrix m in (1) can be used for blockmatrix product. For example, let  A=array(rep(1,3),c(3,1)), B=A, C=A, D=A. Set library(blockmatrix). L =list(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D), mv <- array(c("A","B","C","D"),c(2,2)), BB <- blockmatrix(value=mv,list=l), P=blockmatmult(m,BB). The product does not work.

Comment: You need to create an object of blockmatrix class using the info in ?blockmatrix . Read that carefully and also play around with the examples in that package if you want to use it.  Your question was not about that package but just asked for list output.

Comment: I think I got it now. The thing is that the command matrix(unlist(m), 2, byrow = TRUE) returns m as a blockmatrix whose [1,2] element, say, looking something like > m[1,2] [[1]] [1]  4 10 18. However, if we write mm=matrix(unlist(m), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE), and subsequently define m2=as.blockmatrix(mm,nrowe=1, ncole=3), then the [1,2] blockmatrix element is now read as > m2[1,2] [1]  4 10 18 , which comes without the index [[1]]. It is all sorted out. Thanks again by the way for showing the way. Regards.